# How to include external <img> tag in cordova ios app

Tags: html, ios, cordova, cordova-ios

In our IOS Cordova app. we are trying to include an `<img>` tag reference to an external hosted image with the following in our index.html:

`<img src ="http://www.deviantsart.com/1lpfnfg.jpg">`

I suspected it may have something to do with domain whitelisting but here is our current config.xml:

`<access origin="*"/>`

Instead of rendering this image in main canvas after deviceready, the output of this valid image link is an empty square. When I clicked on the img link in the Safari debug console, I see a "?" icon.

This is really puzzling why an X-platform app. running in IOS can't display an externally-hosted image? Is this just a problem of using the correct img markup syntax?

Thank you.
J

Answer (score 0):

loading a static image from web on mobile app is bad idea (image that it's source is known before run time), because if the user won't have internet you'll be in trouble + loading might be very slow.

you are probably getting cross origin issue, you can try loading the image with Anonymous [crossOrigin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/CORS_settings_attributes) Tag

```
<img crossorigin="Anonymous" src="http://www.deviantsart.com/1lpfnfg.jpg">
```

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion however, we do check for network connectivity in app. prior to loading this image. Adding the crossorigin tag did not fix the issue - image still does not load.

Comment: this specific image or every image? because this is a large image that might get a memory warning